# Displaying data in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I have created two label and i want to display the question in one label and answer with option in other label .
I have to display options with selectable button just like multiple choice question type in single line to select , only one answer should be selected at a time

Suggestions will be appreciated

I hereby attached my code along with the screenshot of my output screen of emulator.

Code -

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var topicLabel: UILabel!


 var dictionary1:[Int:String] = [0:"Whether you have experienced Pricking-pain, Desquamation,itching or dry skin sensation during seasonal alternate.",
1:"Whether your skin apt to flush( Redness) in hot humid environment ",
 2:"Whether your skin has multiple disernible dilated capillaries.",
 3:"whether you have once been diagnosed atopic dermatitis or seborrheic dermatitis."]


var dictionary2:[Int:Array<String>] = [0:["Never","Seldom","Usually","Always"],
1:["Never","Seldom","Usually","Always"],
2:["Never","Seldom","Usually","Always"],
3:["Yes", "No"]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        titleLabel.text = "Fill Skin Type Survey Form "
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        topicLabel.text = "Are You with sensitive skin type ?"
        topicLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)



    }



    //TableView



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return dictionary1.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
        //cell.questionLabel.text = NSObject.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: [indexPath.row])

       cell.questionLabel.text = dictionary1[indexPath.row]

        cell.questionLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        //cell.optionsLabel.text = dictionary2[indexPath.row]

        let arr = dictionary2[indexPath.row]

       var strr = String()
        for str in arr! {
           strr = strr + str
       }
        cell.optionsLabel.text = strr

        cell.optionsLabel.textColor = UIColor.black


            return cell
    }
```

Comment: are you using `UITableViewCell` or `CustomCell`?

Comment: can you show the constraints you have added to cell?

Comment: @Kuldeep TableViewCell

Comment: @Priyal I have added Suggested constraints

Comment: @Sudhir, review my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `UILabel` `numberOfLines` and `lineBreakMode` property.

Don't forget to add `heightForRowAt` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dictionary1.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell

    // FOR FIRST DICTIONARY
    cell.questionLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.questionLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

    cell.questionLabel?.text = dictionary1[indexPath.row]

    // FOR SECOND DICTIONARY
    cell.optionsLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.optionsLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

    cell.optionsLabel?.text = dictionary2[indexPath.row]?.joined(separator: "\n")

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 350.0
}
```

Now it looks like this.
[image]

Comment: @Sudhir, did you set `UILabel` `numberOfLines` and `lineBreakMode` property? and did you implement `heightForRow` method?

Comment: @Sudhir, then there should be constraint issue, **Refer this Demo**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6iagl24fxo14iar/Demo.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Sudhir, what did you missing? constraint?

Comment: The code is running but it is not displaying the full data , only partial data is shown , any suggestion ?

Comment: @Sudhir partial data means?

Comment: The  String data of Dictionary 1 is not displayed completely , only single line is displayed on table view

Comment: @Sudhir, Please download the demo again that I shared, it works completely. try to add long text in your 1st dictionary.

Comment: @Sudhir send me your project, I will let you know what's the issue in your code.

Comment: @Sudhir, without checking code how can I told you why your code is not working?

Comment: here is my file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/b308feiin3isg7o/app.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Sudhir, send proper link.

Comment: @Sudhir, You set Fixed height to top label than how can it grow as per text content? There's constraint issue. Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9immy401vf3mse/app.zip?dl=0

Comment: thanks buddy , I am a new in Swift , So not aware of the constraints , I just did suggested constraints by Xcode !!! Anyway thanks a lot for your guidance

Comment: @Sudhir, ok, np If you want to learn about constraints than this is good tutorial : https://www.raywenderlich.com/160527/auto-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started

Comment: Hey buddy , need your help regarding updated question